# Summing real numbers from a text file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

We have the following file:

```
more /home/avrg.bc.txt

    3.4
    54.2
    4.5
    3.5
    2.3
    89.6
    .
    .
    .
```

We want to calculate the sum of the numbers in the file  as `3.4 + 54.2 + 4.5 + .....`

How can we use `awk` to sum all the float numbers and give the sum total?

Comment: See [How can I quickly sum all numbers in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702564/how-can-i-quickly-sum-all-numbers-in-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' avrg.bc.txt
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `sum += $0` is faster: awk doesn't have to split each record into fields.